# How to convert all the images into all the sub-folders and convert it into an h5 file?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning, h5py

In below code I have read images from the directory as shown in code and the labels and using matplotlib I am able to plot the images, but I am having problem to save all these data in an h5 file.I have 15 classes(i.e. 15 folders) in folder `PlantVillage`.

```py
train_path = '/home/snehil/Desktop/plantdisease/plantvillage/PlantVillage'

train_x = '/home/snehil/Desktop/plantdisease/plantvillage/PlantVillage/Pepper__bell___Bacterial_spot'

train_batches = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    classes=[
        'Pepper__bell___Bacterial_spot',
        'Pepper__bell___healthy', 
        'Potato___Early_blight',
        'Potato___healthy',
        'Potato___Late_blight', 
        'Tomato_Bacterial_spot',
        'Tomato_Early_blight',
        'Tomato_healthy',
        'Tomato_Late_blight',
        'Tomato_Leaf_Mold',
        'Tomato_Septoria_leaf_spot',
        'Tomato_Spider_mites_Two_spotted_spider_mite',
        'Tomato__Target_Spot',
        'Tomato__Tomato_mosaic_virus', 
        'Tomato__Tomato_YellowLeaf__Curl_Virus'
     ],
     batch_size=10
)


# plots images with labels within jupyter notebook
def plots(ims, figsize=(12, 6), rows=1, interp=False, titles=None):
    if type(ims[0]) is np.ndarray:
        ims = np.array(ims).astype(np.uint8)
        if (ims.shape[-1] != 3):
            ims = ims.transpose((0, 2, 3, 1))

    f = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)

    cols = len(ims) // rows if len(ims) % 2 == 0 else len(ims) // rows + 1

    for i in range(len(ims)):
        sp = f.add_subplot(rows, cols, i+1)
        sp.axis('Off')
        if titles is not None:
            sp.set_title(titles[i], fontsize=16)
        plt.imshow(ims[i], interpolation=None if interp else 'none')


imgs, labels = next(train_batches)
plots(imgs, titles=labels)
```

And I have tried this piece of code, and it's just consuming all my RAM.

```
import h5py
h5_train = h5py.File("train_x.h5", 'w')
h5_train.create_dataset("data_train", data=np.array(train_batches))
print(h5_train)
h5_train.close()
```

Comment: I am not sure that the description of the code is related to the question. Could you edit the question?

Comment: Is path correct?  `/home/Desktop/`

Comment: @Dr.H.Lecter I  have edited the question , maybe it's clear now.

Comment: I'm not a ML guy, so don't understand your training code. When you say 'consuming all my RAM', I suspect you are trying to write too much data at once. What kind of data is in `train_batches`? And how big is it? You may need to write training data incrementally. Create a loop on train_batches members and write the member data to HDF5 one at a time.

Comment: @kcw78 yeah I figured out that, the problem was that the total file size  was 11 GB  and due to that my ram was getting all consumed.I created loop and written to HDF5 one at a time and it worked.I was skeptical of that but thanks to your comment I think thats the way to go.